# How to run a 'While Loop' alongside a tkinter mainloop - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

My code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from multiprocessing import Process

def main():
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Would you rather?')
    root.geometry('1040x540+50+50')
    root.resizable(0,0)

    main = tk.Frame(root, width = 1040, height = 540, background = '')
    main.place(x=0, y=0)
    root.mainloop()


def test():
    while True:
        print('hello')               
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target = main())
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target = test())
    p2.start()
```

My aim is to run my while loop (print 'hello constantly) while running my Tkinter program without it pausing or closing. Am I doing something wrong, are you able to even do it?

Comment: You should not run `main()` in a thread.  Also `target=test()` should be `target=test`.

Comment: I tried running main as 'main()' and it still isn't working.

Comment: You should start the `test()` thread first and then run `main()`.

Comment: My loop runs but the Tkinter one won't.

Comment: Did you change `target=test()` to `target=test`?

Comment: Changed it and it works, thanks. Is there a way to pause the thread for a certain amount of seconds?